# Trouble using QuickTime method

Tags: metadata, quicktime

I'm trying to use [QTCopyMovieMetaData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTRef_MovieProperties/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/QTCopyMovieMetaData) defined in Quicktime/Movies.h. I've linked both QTKit and QuickTime frameworks to my target and imported everything necessary into my header and implementation files:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <QTKit/QTKit.h>
#import <QuickTime/QuickTime.h>
#import "Quicktime/Movies.h"
```

However, I'm getting compiler errors for not recognizting QTCopyMovieMetaData or QTMetaDataRef (also declared in Movies.h).

The example code in [QTMediaEditor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/QTMetadataEditor/Introduction/Intro.html) uses QTCopyMovieMetaData and compiles sucessfully on my machine for a 32 bit target, but not a 64 bit target. My app won't compile for 32 bit. Comparing my app's build settings with QTMediaEditors build settings, I don't see what would cause that difference.

Any advice on what might be blocking the QuickTime framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QTCopyMovieMetaData` function is not available in 64-bit. Note that the entire contents of Movies.h are subject to an `#if !__LP64__` condition; everything in that file is only declared on 32-bit architectures.

> My app won't compile for 32 bit.

If you mean you're dropping 32-bit support, good; QuickTime already has.

You need to [use the Metadata framework to examine the file](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/MDItemRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/MDItemCreateWithURL). Note that this will only work if the file is on a volume with a Spotlight index, and only if the file has been indexed. There is no replacement in QTKit (not as of Snow Leopard, anyway) for the QuickTime framework's QTMetaData API.